# Why cannot choose group on the pending request

Tags: sharepoint-online, access-requests

We have identified that when a user requests access to the site, in the pending requests we can choose the selected groups in the type of permissions. This adds the user to the group.
[image]

When the library has broken inheritance and the user requests access directly to the library, it is NOT possible to choose any of the established groups as type of permissions.

[image]

Is there a way to be able to choose the groups from "Access request and invitation" even if they request access to an element that has broken inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, we are not able to choose the groups from "Access request and invitation" if users request access to a library/list with unique permissions.